# Sharepoint 2010 Using built-in accounts error SPTraceV4

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have been wrestling with a SharePoint 2010 service identify alert.  When I go to Monitoring and under the Health Analyzer I click Review Problems and solutions I see the following message:

**Built-in accounts are used as application pool or service identities.**

When I click this to launch Review problems and solutions window it states:

**Using built-in accounts like Network Service or Local System as application pool or as service identities is not supported in a farm configuration.  The following services are currently running as built-in identities on one or more servers: SPTraceV4(Windows Service)**

I have found many variations of a script to run in the SharePoint PowerShell (must be ran as administrator). However, They all seem have slight variations from one another and I can't get any of them to run without errors.  Here is an example of a script, or set of command lines, that I recently tried to use:

As soon as the second line runs

```
$TraceAccountDomain,$TraceAccountUser = $TraceAccount -Split "\"
```

I get this error

```
Bad argument to operator '-split': parsing "\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern..At line:1 char:61 + $TraceAccountDomain,$TraceAccountUser = $TraceAccount -Split <<<<  "\" + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think your Split needs to escape the `"\"` since it uses regex. so `-Split "\\"`

Comment: That was fast and absolutely correct.  I am able to run the script with no errors.  And it fixed my problem ! Tanks!!!

Comment: For the record, amd Matt help[ed me fix this, the entire script for fixing the "The following services are currently running as built-in identities on one or more servers: SPTraceV4(Windows Service)" error in SharePoint 2010 is as follow:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Split` operator uses Regex for its matches. Slash, being a special character, needs to be escaped to match a literal slash

```
$TraceAccountDomain,$TraceAccountUser = $TraceAccount -Split "\\"
```

That should work just fine.